# How to download web content using C?

Tags: c, http, parsing

I have to write a C parser for online blogs and different word manipulation features.

I know how to parse / tokenise stings in C, but how would you on execution download the pages content to a local `/tmp` directory as an HTML file so I can save the information (the blogs) into a string using I/O?

Or, just grab the block of text directly from the page I am viewing...

My system could be either Ubuntu or Windows 7, so I dont think `wget` will cut it. Please help.

Comment: You can get wget binaries for windows. But as Georg says, libcurl is probably the go.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/):

> libcurl is a free and easy-to-use client-side URL transfer library, supporting [...] HTTP, HTTPS, [...]
>
> libcurl is highly portable, it builds and works identically on numerous platforms, including [...] Linux, [...] Windows, [...]

Comment: sounds like this is what im looking for, after reading back my own spec it sounds like im building an rss reader app. is there any pitfalls I need to be aware of with C/libcurl graphic libraries if I take this direction

Comment: @JB87: I'm not sure what libcurl has to do with graphic libraries? If you are going for a cross-platform GUI using gtk+ or something like this then it might be easier to go with their fitting implementations instead.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can make use of [`system`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/system/) to execute [`wget`](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/)

Answer (score 0):

And there is [libsoup](http://live.gnome.org/LibSoup) too.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN: [URLDownloadToFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775123(VS.85).aspx)